# New DateTimeOffset from string

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I want to create a new `DateTimeOffset` with `offset = -5` from a string

I do :

```
string dt = "11082016";    
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "MMddyyyy", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                    DateTimeStyles.None);    
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(date, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));
```

Is it possible to create directly a `DateTimeOffset` without passing by `DateTime` ?

Comment: `DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 11, 8, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));`

Comment: Can you give any reason of using `DateTimeOffset`, instead of `DateTime`, or `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @LeiYang I need to use this for work with time zone awareness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create directly a DateTimeOffset without passing by
>   DateTime ?

No, that's not possible.

Every [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) instance *has to* have it's `DateTime` part. You *can't* create a `DateTimeOffset` instance just with a [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value.

[Of course it has some constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) that doesn't take `DateTime` as a parameter *directly* like;

- DateTimeOffset(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Calendar, TimeSpan)
- DateTimeOffset(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, TimeSpan)
- DateTimeOffset(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, TimeSpan)
- DateTimeOffset(Int64, TimeSpan)

But those `Int32` and `Int64` values are *still* generate a `Datetime` internally for current instance [`.DateTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime).

> I want to create a new DateTimeOffset with offset = -5 from a string

If you could do that, you wouldn't *need* that string, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can:

```
string dt = "11082016";
string o = "-5";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dt + o, "MMddyyyyz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Though it's not very pretty - the point is `DateTimeOffset` also has a `ParseExact` method.