# How to change type from String to DateTimeOffset object

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to change the type of a string to a `DateTimeOffset` object.

```
var Result = Convert.ChangeType("2017-02-27T18:00:00.0000000+01:00",
    typeof(DateTimeOffset), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I've tried also with these strings

`2017-02-27 18:00:00Z`

`02/27/2017 18:00:00`

But I always obtain an `InvalidCastException`.

What is the correct string to pass to the `ChangeType`? For development reasons I cannot use `DateTimeOffset.Parse` method.

Comment: Can you use `DateTime.Parse`? If so, converting `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` is trivial

Comment: Unfortunately for development reasons I cannot use DateTimeOffset.Parse

Comment: Just an FYI, DateTime.Parse and DateTimeOffset.Parse are not the same.  He was asking about an alternate function, not the one you specifically said you couldn't use in the post.

Comment: What does "for development reasons" mean in this context? Are you also prevented from implementing your own parser?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `DateTime.Parse()`, then try this:

```
var dateTime = (DateTime)Convert.ChangeType(stringDateTime,
        typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
```

This seems to work for all of the sample input strings in your question.

---

Alternatively, you can try `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter()`:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffset));
var result = converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)) ?
    (DateTimeOffset)converter.ConvertFrom(stringDateTime) :
    new DateTimeOffset();
```

But this doesn't work when trying to convert from `02/27/2017 18:00:00`.

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476488/new-datetimeoffset-from-string?rq=1) for some details about `string` to `DateTimeOffset` conversion.